# register to a question

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

**Think of the following scenario:**

You find a great answer with a code sample and deciding to use it in production. The code that you found has a flaw which being resolved sometime later on.

**Result:**

You will not be aware of that flaw as some bugs are elusive in nature (unless you get customers complaining)

One way to go around that is to add a button “Alert Me” which will alert you of such a change (and others)

This question sparked this idea:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26696355/895667

Comment: The "favourites" feature does exactly this (click the star underneath vote buttons on a question)

Comment: oh nice! thanks for your comment

Comment: @Flexo No, you don't get notified when your favorites are modified.

Comment: @Scimonster they change state when viewed from your profile under the favourites tab to indicate activity and there's a counter too. I don't think there's an official RSS feed for it, but you can get it from the public API too and [someone has a API->RSS gateway](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25194/rss-feed-for-favorite-questions#comment763019_64987) e.g. mine are at: http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/2.2/users/168175//favorites?site=stackoverflow

Comment: This would be a nice feature for a github repo (in fact I'm sure it exists already). For a SO answer, not so much.

Comment: Why this question was down voted? some folks are not sure about the answer...

Comment: Just for your info: [voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): *"On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can already follow questions:

1. You can star the question, marking it as a favourite. Every time the question is edited, or any of its answers (including new answers), or comments are posted to it, the question will be marked as 'active' in your favourites tab. You'll need to check that tab in your profile to see if anything changed.
2. You can use the per-question RSS feed, adding it to an RSS reader of your choice. The feed entries are the answers, if and when they come in. You can find the feed in the bottom-right-hand corner of the page:

   [image: question feed link]